# calculating the Gamma function for negative real values (C++, Boost)

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, factorial, gamma-function

The following infinite serious require the calculation of factorial for non-integer, negative, real numbers:
[image: Infinite serious:]

(it is a way to calculate the circumference of an ellipse, a and b are the semi-major and semi minor axis and h is defined as:
h = (a-b)^2/(a+b)^2)

The factorial function can be extended to negative values via the Gamma function which is defined for all the real numbers that are not negative integers.

While coding the serious I tried boost::math::factorial and boost::math::tgamma which gives results only down to -1 (not included) -1.5 for example give an error.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/math/special_functions/factorials.hpp>

    int main()
    {
        double x;
        double f;
        double tg;

        x = -0.5;
        f = boost::math::factorial<double>(x);
        tg = boost::math::tgamma<double>(x);
        cout << "factorial of " << x << " = " << f << endl;
        cout << "tgamma of " << x << " = " << tg << endl << endl;

        x = -1.5;
        f = boost::math::factorial<double>(x);
        tg = boost::math::tgamma<double>(x);
        cout << "factorial of " << x << " = " << f << endl;
        cout << "tgamma of " << x << " = " << tg << endl << endl;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

the output:

> factorial of -0.5 = 1
> tgamma of -0.5 = -3.54491
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_implboost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::domain_error >'
> what():  Error in function boost::math::tgamma(long double): Evaluation of tgamma at a negative integer 0.
> Aborted (core dumped)

boost factorial:
[boost factorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/factorials/sf_factorial.html)
boost tgamma:
[boost tgamma](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_gamma/tgamma.html)

My questions:

1. Is there an alternative to boost that can calculate the gamma function for its negative domain?
2. I could not find in the boost documentation linked above mention of the implemented domain for factorials and tgamma functions. In fact I might simply be using them wrong. What is the way to ascertain what is indeed the domain/correct usage?

Thanks.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why did not you use `std::tgamma` ? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tgamma

Comment: In the last boost tgamma documentation, a figure is provided, which shows that you should not have problem in calculating it for x = -1.5. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_gamma/tgamma.html

Comment: @Damien thank you, I did not know that std::tgamma exists. 
and yes, the image from the boost documentation apply that boost::tgamma function is indeed defined for the negative domain, but the domain is not defined explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what's going wrong. The `boost::math::factorial` function takes an `unsigned` integer **by definition**:

```
template <class T>
inline T factorial(unsigned i)
{
   return factorial<T>(i, policies::policy<>());
}
```

This means that if you call it with a double, it will get implicitly converted to unsigned. That's not what you want. Also, `factorial` ends up using `tgamma` internally, so you get this:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/factorials.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void foo(long double x) {
    using namespace boost::math;
    try {
        auto f = factorial<long double>(x);
        std::cout << "factorial of " << static_cast<unsigned>(x) << " = " << f << "\n";
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "error at " << static_cast<unsigned>(x) << ": " << std::quoted(e.what()) << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::unitbuf;
    foo(-2);
}
```

Will end up doing this:

```
#0  boost::math::tgamma<long double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> > (a=4294967295, z=...)
    at /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_73_0/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:1994
No locals.
#1  0x0000555555558eb3 in boost::math::factorial<long double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> > (i=4294967294, pol=...)
    at /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_73_0/boost/math/special_functions/factorials.hpp:44
        result = -0.667762310955655363645
#2  0x0000555555558674 in boost::math::factorial<long double> (i=4294967294)
    at /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_73_0/boost/math/special_functions/factorials.hpp:53
No locals.
#3  0x0000555555557792 in foo (x=-2) at /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:7
        f = <invalid float value>
#4  0x000055555555791f in main () at /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:16
No locals.
```

So it's attempting to give you `boost::math::factorial<long double> (i=4294967294)`

### Fix

Don't use `factorials` for other than non-negative integers.

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jq64qE)**

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/factorials.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void foo(long double x) {
    using namespace boost::math;
    try {
        auto tg = tgamma<long double>(x);
        std::cout << "tgamma    of " << x << " = " << tg << "\n" << std::endl;
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "error at " << x << ": " << std::quoted(e.what()) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    for (auto x : { 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., -.2, -2., -.5, -1.5 })
        foo(x);
}
```

Prints:

```
tgamma    of 1 = 1

tgamma    of 2 = 1

tgamma    of 3 = 2

tgamma    of 4 = 6

tgamma    of 5 = 24

tgamma    of -0.2 = -5.82115

error at -2: "Error in function boost::math::tgamma<long double>(long double): Evaluation of tgamma at a negative integer -2."
tgamma    of -0.5 = -3.54491

tgamma    of -1.5 = 2.36327
```

It understandably overflows at `-2`, but that's correct.

Comment: thank you very much. I tried both the std::tgamma and also your code and both works. much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Gamma functions are part of the standard library since C++11 [1].

The usage is as follows:

```
#include <cmath>

std::tgamma(-0.5) # -3.5449077
std::lgamma(-0.5) # 1.2655121
```

You might as well use `tgammal` and `tgammaf` for `long double` and `float` types correspondingly.

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to reproduce your problem using g++-10 on Mac, using boost.math commit hash 87929356790ad0 (current `develop`), but I get:

```
factorial of -0.5 = 1
tgamma of -0.5 = -3.54491

factorial of -1.5 = 1
tgamma of -1.5 = 2.36327
```

So more information is necessary, Boost version, OS, compiler, so on.

Comment: Maybe you can supply _your_ platform details as well?

Comment: @user14717 thank you very much, at least now I know that in general it supposed to work even if not in the version  I have, 
my platform details: 
Ubuntu 18.04
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~18.04.1) 
libboost-dev version 1.65.1.0ubuntu1